# Ellipse dans des plages de nombres : « six à sept cent »

Tags: nombres, ellipse

Il y a deux possibilités dont l'une (comportant l'ellipse) s'entend dans la langue parlée mais dont je ne suis pas sûr de la validité dans le texte.

- Ils ont trouvé **six** à sept cents éléments.
- Ils ont trouvé **six cents** à sept cents éléments.

L'habitude de cette ellipse dans la langue parlée semble indiquer une seule possibilité : « six cents à sept cents ». Je ne pense pas que l'ajout de la préposition « **de** » change quoi que ce soit (Ils ont trouvé de cinq à six cents éléments.). Cependant il semble que cette forme puisse être interprétée de deux façon puisqu'il n'y a pas d'autre moyen simple de dire « du nombre « six » au nombre  sept cents »; doit-on considérer la forme elliptique comme du langage relâché à éviter dans le texte et même dans la langue parlée? Son emploi serait-il conditionnel à un contexte dans lequel « six éléments » n'aurait pas de sens?

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas d'une *abréviation*. D'une ***ellipse*** à la rigueur.

Comment: @aCOSwt Ah! Oui, encore cette erreur, on me l'a déjà fait remarquer mais je ne parviens pas à me débarrasser de la fausse idée; merci du rappel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le problème de l'ambiguïté est facilement levé **à l'écrit** à condition d'écrire les nombres... en suivant les recommandations contemporaines.

- De 600 à 700 => De six à sept cent**s**
- De 6 à 700 => De six à **sept-cents**.

Ce trait d'union entre *sept* et *cents* lèvera l'ambigüité.

À l'oral c'est évidemment beaucoup plus compliqué et, comme c'est souvent le cas seule la situation ou le contexte permettront de lever l'ambiguïté... ou pas!

Nota : À l'oral on peut aussi marquer le second cas par une pause plus importante entre *six, à* et *sept* que entre *sept* et *cent* mais... cela reste tout de même hasardeux.

EDIT : on observera accessoirement que dans le second cas (*De six à sept-cents*) *six* et *sept-cents* sont des adjectifs numéraux. Dans le premier (*six à sept cents*), si *six* et *sept* restent des adjectifs numéraux, *cent* est quant à lui un substantif.
(On pourrait tout aussi bien d'ailleurs le remplacer par *centaine*, ce qui serait d'ailleurs une solution pour lever l'ambiguïté à l'oral.)

Comment: **Sept-cent** est incorrect tant en orthographe traditionnelle qu'en suivant les recommandations de 1990. Cette forme ne peut donc pas permettre de lever l’ambiguïté à l'écrit.

Comment: @jlliagre : Exact pour l'oubli du s à cent. Corrigé. Mais ce n'est pas cela qui lève l'ambiguïté. **C'est le trait d'union**.

Comment: Ah, ok. Je retire mon -1, mais reste dubitatif sur le fait que cette subtilité soit facilement comprise. On pourrait aussi suggérer **de six-à-sept-cents** dans le premier cas... ;-)

Comment: Pourquoi avoir mis le **s** du premier cents en gras ? C'est ce qui m'a induit en erreur.

Comment: @jlliagre : Comme je viens, à retard, de le préciser dans l'EDIT, *cent* peut être adjectif numéral ou nom masculin ou encore nom masculin invariable. J'ai graissé le *s* final pour caractériser le fait qu'il ne s'agissait pas du nom masculin invariable.

Answer (score 3):

Avec les valeurs données, le risque d'ambiguïté est nul. Le sens implicite qui sera toujours compris est celui de 600 à 700 et l'ellipse ne pose donc pas de problème.

Dans l'hypothèse improbable où il faudrait vraiment commencer à six, on pourra préciser :

> Ils ont trouvé de six éléments à sept cents éléments.

ou

> Ils ont trouvé entre six éléments et sept cents éléments.